# Xamarin - Deselect Listview Item does not work properly in iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, listviewitem

I have a listview and I want an Item to deselect if I tap it again. So basically I tap an Item it gets selected I tap it again it gets deselected.
My Code is working just fine on Android. It also works on iOS the only thing that doesn't work is if I tap an Item its background color changes but if I deselect it its background color should change back. That happens on Android but not on iOS. Any ideas why "mylistview.selecteditem = null" works properly on Android but not on iOS?

```
public void AnwesenheitTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item as Anwesenheit != Anwesenheit)
    {
        Anwesenheit = args.Item as Anwesenheit;
        ViewModel.Anwesenheit = args.Item as Anwesenheit;
        if (Anwesenheit == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ViewModel.AlsAbwesendEintragenButton = true;
        ViewModel.Datum = Anwesenheit.Datum;
        AnwesenheitenDatum.IsEnabled = false;
        if (Anwesenheit.Anmeldungsart == "Früh")
        {
            Anmeldungsart.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (Anwesenheit.Anmeldungsart == "Mittags")
        {
            Anmeldungsart.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Anmeldungsart.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }
        AnwesenheitenLabel.Text = "Anwesenheit bearbeiten:";
        AnwesenheitenButton.Text = "Anwesenheit bearbeiten";
        ViewModel.Edit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Anwesenheit = null;
        ViewModel.Datum = DateTime.Today;
        AnwesenheitenDatum.IsEnabled = true;                
        ViewModel.AlsAbwesendEintragenButton = false;
        Anmeldungsart.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ViewModel.Edit = false;
        AnwesenheitenLabel.Text = "Neue Anwesenheit:";
        AnwesenheitenButton.Text = "Neue Anwesenheit hinzufügen";
        BetreuungsoptionenListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your Xamarin Forms version, there is a bug in Xamarin Forms 3.5 for iOS listview, which is fixed in version 3.6

Comment: Could you attach the bug link ? I test on XF 3.5 and 3.6 , it works fine (background color change back when SelectedItem set to null) with the two version .

Comment: in my dependencies it says Xamarin.Forms (3.0.0.561731). I Installed it with VS 2019 installer... Visual Studio doesnt tell me there is an Update...

Comment: could you share me a basic sample ?

Comment: What do you mean with basic sample? It is a normal Listview and the code above. That is basic, isn't it?

Comment: I used your code but it works fine , send me your project please .